# Why does Facebook suggest friends that only appear in my Google Contacts?

Tags: gmail, facebook, google-contacts

Some time ago (yeah, I admit that was stupid), I granted Facebook to access my Gmail account to look for friends.

While I'm pretty sure I revoked access at some point, Facebook still occasionally suggests new friends that can only come from my Google contact list. I don't have any mutual friends with them and I certainly never want to be friends with them either.

The most incredible thing is that these contacts were added to Google *after* I remember revoking authorization.

So:

- How can I tell Facebook to stay out of my Google Contacts? – or:
- How can I tell Google to block Facebook from accessing them?

I couldn't find any options related to this.

Answer (score 5):

Removing the access to Google wasn't enough. Facebook still stores these contacts, and you have to request to delete them.

This page is available through a custom URL and I couldn't find it in the Help Center.

> https://www.facebook.com/contact_importer/remove_uploads.php

All I had to do is click "Remove" here …

[image]

After a few minutes, my imported Google contacts were deleted:

[image]

Comment: How did you find the url?

Comment: I googled, like, a lot :) — In fact, [there are many "hidden" Facebook forms](http://www.marismith.com/how-contact-facebook-directory-of-forms/), one of them is related to imported contacts.

Comment: That's a LOT. I wonder how that girl found em out.

Comment: Thankyou for this. This has been bugging me for a long time, especially since I have enabled gmail's 2-factor authorisation and single-use passwords, neither of which Facebook has access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have revoked access from Google, there should be no way FB can access them. It might be possible that FB created a copy of your contacts and suggesting from there. And I Don't think there is any way to tell FB to stop suggesting from there.

If you think FB is accessing data even after you revoked access, i.e. it's suggesting people you've added to your contact *after* you revoked the access, you can file a complaint maybe. It should be a bug.

Comment: Well I'm not too sure. Do you know where in Google I could revoke access?

Comment: Here - https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en

Comment: I looked and found Facebook.com, which I removed. Still, Facebook suggests these contacts. Maybe they are still stored on Facebook somewhere.

Comment: Ah, figured it out, see my answer!